# Possible Bug with GNUCash - GNUCash cannot see/open files in OneDrive

Tags: gnucash

I am wondering if anyone has encountered - or has a possible solution to - this bug I have found. I usually store my GNUCash file in OneDrive. However, with the new update of OneDrive, GNUCash cannot see the file. See the error below. Has anyone also seen this error - or know how to correct it?

`Can't parse the URL /Users/<username>/OneDrive/Documents/GnuCashData.gnucash`

Thanks!

Comment: This kind of question is more appropriate in the GnuCash mailing lists.

Comment: Or https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to find your GnuCash data file in OneDrive using File Explorer.  Double click on the file and GnuCash should automatically fire up as the appropriate application to run a file with a *xxx.gnucash* file extension.

GnuCash maintains a list of the four-most-recent files that were opened in the application, allowing you to quickly open one of those four files from the GnuCash *File* menu.

My guess is that once you've opened your data file as above, GnuCash will remember the correct pathway to your data file and it will be automatically loaded the next time you open GnuCash.